# SQL JOIN Multiplies Result Set - Cartesian Product

Tags: sql, oracle, join, cartesian-product

I have a base table and I want to join 2 more tables to get all the data I need. Upon running my query I get a Cartesian product because 2 of the tables (the main table and the other table I am joining) is being joined by a `non-unique` key.

Here's an example:

#### Invoice (i)

```
id    order_id       name             comment
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1     500            Males            Mice
2     500            Females          Mice
3     500            Courier Fee      Within City
```

#### Order (o)

```
id    order_number
------------------------------
500   AN5246516264
```

#### Order Items (oi)

```
id    order_id       strain_id    species_id      comments
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1100  500            858          9876            Mice
1101  500            858          9876            Mice
1102  500            NULL         NULL            Within City
```

Using the tables defined above here's my query:

#### Query

```
SELECT
    i.name, i.comment,
    o.order_number,
    oi.strain_id, oi.species_id
FROM invoice i
LEFT JOIN order o
    ON i.order_id = o.id
LEFT JOIN order_items oi
    ON o.id = oi.order_id
```

After running the query I get a Cartesian product as shown below (not necessarily in order):

```
name         comment        order_number     strain_id    species_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Males        Mice           AN5246516264     858          9876 ---> I want this row
Males        Mice           AN5246516264     858          9876
Males        Within City    AN5246516264     NULL         NULL
Females      Mice           AN5246516264     858          9876
Females      Mice           AN5246516264     858          9876 ---> I want this row
Females      Within City    AN5246516264     NULL         NULL
Courier Fee  Mice           AN5246516264     858          9876
Courier Fee  Mice           AN5246516264     858          9876
Courier Fee  Within City    AN5246516264     NULL         NULL ---> I want this row
```

I understand what's happening here and I know why it results in a Cartesian product but I don't know how to solve my problem.

I just want to append the `order_number`, `strain_id` and the `species_id` to the `Invoice (i)` table.

And yes the table structure is built somewhat in a weird way. I do believe the database designer was intoxicated when he made the tables but that's not something I can change now.

Any suggestions?

#### EDIT

I've looked at all 3 tables and I can't find any other columns to join them with. I'm left with the `order_id`.

Comment: The question is, "how can I link an invoice item to an order item". Ask this question theoretically, not for the database problem here. In reality, there is NOT a specific link, even the comments are not unique. The only possibility I can see is either you assume the order of the items is the same in both tables (in which case you can use orderby to try and join them) or you have to ignore the invoice or order items tables so that you don't get the multiplication problem.

Comment: What's unique about the rows that you want to keep?

Comment: Building off of @Lukos, you could range the rows over the order id on the Order items table and join that rank id to the id of the invoice table. You'd have to check the process that adds data to those tables to make sure they were inserted sequentially the same as the Order Items table.

Comment: @Lukos Yes that is a problem since I don't know why it was built this way. But I can only see the `order_id` as being the only column that I can use to join them. I do need data from all 3 tables so ignoring 2 of them is not an option. As for the order, well I don't want to rely on that since other records might not be in the same format.

Comment: @Dave The rows I labeled that I want to keep are the rows that I actually expect.

Comment: Yes, but WHY do you want to keep those rows?  What's different about them?  If you can define that, you can add a WHERE clause to filter your results.

Comment: In this case, those match up because there are the same number of invoices to an order as there are order lines. Will that always be the case? Also, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Dave I can't figure out what to put in a `WHERE` clause because there really isn't one.

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes I clearly understand why it results in a Cartesian product. I'm using Oracle SQL.

Comment: When you're looking at that list of results, how do you know which ones to put "---> I want this row" next to?

Comment: @Dave The `Mice` has `species_id` and `strain_id` while the `Courier Fee` has a `NULL` value on those columns. But that's not a clear and cut way to do this as this is just a small subset of the records stored in the database.

Comment: Sounds like `WHERE strain_id IS NOT NULL AND species_id IS NOT NULL` is a start at least?

Comment: @Dave Then I would not get the `Courier Fee` row.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you want now.  What if there are multiple `Order Items` with different `strain_id` and `species_id` values for the same order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103629/discussion-between-patrick-gregorio-and-dave).

Comment: Are you able to see how the invoice rows were generated - particularly where the name value came from? And are there other columns in the tables (particularly order_items) you haven't shown, which might have been used to look up the name for each invoice? You've said there's no direct link, and from the columns you've shown that seems to be the case, but there must be more to it. Whether you can see enough to figure that out with your vendor responding is unclear though.

Comment: @AlexPoole The software does the actual inserts and I don't have access to see that. I've looked at all the columns for those 3 tables (yes I hid most of them here) but most if not all of them are irrelevant. Yeah I'm stuck to just waiting for the vendor's response for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could number rows in tables `i` and `oi` at first using function `row_number()` and then use it as part of joining condition:

```
with i as  (select row_number() over (partition by order_id order by id) rn, i.*  
              from invoice i),
     oi as (select row_number() over (partition by order_id order by id) rn, oi.* 
              from order_items oi)
select i.name, i.comments, o.order_number, oi.strain_id, oi.species_id
  from i left join orders o on i.order_id = o.id
  left join oi on oi.order_id = o.id and oi.rn = i.rn
```

Test data and output:

```
create table invoice (id number(4), order_id number(4), 
  name varchar2(15), comments varchar2(20));
insert into invoice values (1, 500, 'Males', 'Mice');
insert into invoice values (2, 500, 'Females' ,'Mice');
insert into invoice values (3, 500, 'Courier Fee', 'Within City');
--
create table orders (id number(4), order_number varchar2(15));
insert into orders values (500, 'AN5246516264');
--
create table order_items(id number(5), order_id number(4), 
  strain_id number(5), species_id number(5), comments varchar2(20));
insert into order_items values(1100, 500, 858,  9876, 'Mice');
insert into order_items values(1101, 500, 858,  9876, 'Mice');
insert into order_items values(1102, 500, NULL, NULL, 'Within City');
```

Output:

```
NAME            COMMENTS             ORDER_NUMBER    STRAIN_ID SPECIES_ID
--------------- -------------------- --------------- --------- ----------
Males           Mice                 AN5246516264          858       9876
Females         Mice                 AN5246516264          858       9876
Courier Fee     Within City          AN5246516264
```

Comment: I could see this working `if and only if` the items are in order. If not then I'm going to have a wrong result set.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it works so I'm upvoting it. But I can't accept it as the answer because I can't be sure that all rows from both tables are in the same order.

Comment: I ran this now on actual live data and I'm getting a few weird results because of the ordering. The number of rows is correct though. So yeah, this didn't work but it was a good attempt and I'd choose this solution in a perfect world where the ordering isn't an issue.

Comment: I modified the query a little bit and I was able to fix the issue. It now works as how I want it to. Instead of `order by id` I used `order by rownum`. Thanks.